# How can I get my regex route attribute to match an empty value in addition to validating a user supplied value?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, url-routing

I have this controller and action:

```
[Route("categories")]
public class CategoriesController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("{*category:regex(^[[A-Za-z0-9/]]*$)}")]
    public IActionResult ViewObjectsInCategory([FromRoute] string category)
    {
        return Ok(category ?? ""); // for now, just echo what you inputted
    }
}
```

I'm intending this action to accept the following url routes:

```
/categories
/categories/abc
/categories/abc/def
/categories/abc/def/1234/ghi
```

Essentially, the user can put anything they want after `/categories` in the url (including nothing) as long as it's an uppercase letter, lowercase letter, digit, or forward slash. If the user puts in a non-valid character, they should receive a 404.

The code posted will correctly route my listed requests for all but the first entry (`/categories`). It returns a 404 when I want it to execute my action.

Looking at the logs, ASP.Net core is absolutely rejecting the route to my action:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/categories
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering.HostFilteringMiddleware[0]
      Wildcard detected, all requests with hosts will be allowed.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware[4]
      The request path /categories does not match a supported file type
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher[1001]
      1 candidate(s) found for the request path '/categories'
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher[1003]
      Endpoint 'MyApp.Controllers.CategoriesController.ViewObjectsInCategory (MyApp)' with route pattern 'categories/{*category:regex(^[A-Za-z0-9/]*$)}' was rejected by constraint 'category':'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Constraints.RegexInlineRouteConstraint' with value '(null)' for the request path '/categories'
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher[1004]
      Endpoint 'MyApp.Controllers.CategoriesController.ViewObjectsInCategory (MyApp)' with route pattern 'categories/{*category:regex(^[A-Za-z0-9/]*$)}' is not valid for the request path '/categories'
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware[2]
      Request did not match any endpoints
```

What can I do to make this route attribute accept both an "empty" value (`/categories`) while also validating that, if present, any user entered value does not have invalid characters?

Comment: what is the `*` behind the `category` for?

Comment: The star `...("{*category...` is to let the routing engine know it's a [catch-all](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2#route-template-reference). The star in the regex pattern is to say "zero or many characters".

Comment: when the endpoint is called using `abc/def/1234/ghi`, what do you expect the value of category string variable to be? `abc` or `abc/def/1234/ghi`

Comment: If the user goes to the endpoint `/categories/abc/def/1234/ghi`, the variable `category` should be `abc/def/1234/ghi`. That part is working, and it echos that value back out.

Answer (score 3):

I've found a way that I think achieves what you're after: you can give an empty default value for the `category` path parameter. Do this by adding a `=` after the regex constraint:

```
[Route("categories")]
public class CategoriesController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("{*category:regex(^[[A-Za-z0-9/]]*$)=}")]
    public IActionResult ViewObjectsInCategory([FromRoute] string category)
    {
        return Ok(category ?? "base route");
    }
}
```

This way if nothing is passed after "/categories", it will use the default value (which is passed as `null` to the method) rather than not matching the endpoint.